# Check if an element is equal to first element of all array elements of a big array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays. Lets assume [[1,2,0], [3,4,10], [5,6,20], [7,8,30]]. I want to check for example, if the number 5 is the first element of all the internal arrays, if number 2 is the second element of all the internal arrays.

I know this can be done with the help of a for loop with the length of the array as its range.

```
for it1 in range(len(array0)):
    if number1 == array0[it1][0] and number2 == array0[it1][1] :
       #do something
```

I wanted to know if there is any better builtin single line code for the above problem. I tried array slicing. But it gave me error.

This is what I tried with slicing. Please check if its correct.

```
if number1 == array0[:,0] and number2 == array0[:,1]:
    #do something
```

Below is an example code.

```
array0 =  [[1,2,0], [3,4,10], [5,6,20], [7,8,30]]
number1 = 5
number2 = 2
if number1 == array0[:,0] and number2 == array0[:,1]:
    print("Numbers match")
```

The error i am getting : 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Edited the original post - added my slicing array code

Comment: I can not verify if it is correct because you have not provided a **[mcve]**, besides you have not answered my question since you point: *But it gave me error.* what is the error? Do you get an error message?

Comment: It is an array. Added more information in the original post

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an int to a list. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
array0 =  np.array([[1,2,0], [3,4,10], [5,6,20], [7,8,30]])
number1 = 5
number2 = 2
if all([number1 == x for x in array0[:,0]]) and \
   all([number2 == x for x in array0[:,1]]):
    print("Numbers match")
```

Moreover you are getting the TypeError because native Python doesn't support slicing `a[:,i]`. So using native Python list:

```
array0 =  [[1,2,0], [3,4,10], [5,6,20], [7,8,30]]
number1 = 5
number2 = 2
if all([number1 == x[0] and number2 == x[1] for x in array0]):
    print("Numbers match")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num1, num2 = 5, 2
print("Match") if all([x[0] == num1 and x[1] == num2 for x in array0]) else print("No match")
```